# Fables - Where do the Cinderella stories fit in?

Tags: comics, suggested-order, vertigo-comics, fables-comics, cinderella

There are two spin offs to *Fables* starring Cinderella:

- Cinderella: From Fabletown with Love
- Cinderella: Fables are Forever

How far do you need to get in the main series before there are no spoilers in these or are they fully stand alone?

Answer (score 3):

You can read *From Fabletown with Love* without spoiling anything, but you'll need to read *Fables are Forever* at a specific point, as its a crossover.

I've just seen the date this was posted, however, so I imagine you already know this!

I'm sorry no-one answered you sooner, and I wasn't around a year ago.

...None of this would have happened if Boy Blue were still with us..